# INSERT, and how to INSERT into multiple tables

Tags: c#, mysql

So I have this form:
[http://i.imgur.com/vZYssQy.png](https://i.imgur.com/vZYssQy.png)

Now the `ID`, `First Name`, `Last Name`, `DOB`, `Address`, `Phone Number` and `Post Code` text boxes are supposed to INSERT into a table called `person` (and this works, it inserts)

My code for this is:

```
public static void insertStudent(int personId, string firstName, string lastName, string DOB, int phoneNumber, string address, int postCode, string majorField, int gradePointAverage)
{
    MySqlConnection conn = connection();
    conn.Open();
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
    cmd.Connection = conn;
    string myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(personId, firstName, lastName, DOB, phoneNumber, address, postCode) VALUES (@personId, @firstName, @lastName, @DOB, @phoneNumber, @address, @postCode)";
    cmd.Prepare();
    cmd.CommandText = myInsertSQL;
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personId", personId);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastName", lastName);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", DOB);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@phoneNumber", phoneNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", address);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@postCode", postCode);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

But the other two text boxes, `GPA` and `Major Field` need to go to a separate table called `student`. And the code I have for this is:

```
 string myInsertSQLStudent = "INSERT INTO student(majorField, gradePointAverage) VALUES (@majorField, @gradePointAverage)";
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.CommandText = myInsertSQLStudent;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@majorField", majorField);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gradePointAverage", gradePointAverage);
            prevID(conn, cmd);
```

which is right underneath the above code. this does not work however, I get a crash and a message telling me `Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails` then it talks about the primary key.

however, it works KIND OF, if I fill out the text boxes, and click `insert` the program crashes, but the `person` table gets filled with the data, but the `student` table does not.

How would I go about making it work?

Thank you!

EDIT:

This is my person table:

```
personId | firstName | lastName | DOB | phoneNumber | address | postCode |

blah     |blah       |blah      |blah |blah         |blah     |blah      |blah
```

this is my student table

```
person_personId | majorField | gradePointAverage |
balh            |blah        |blah               |
```

Comment: What you need is called **transaction**. (And probably disabling autocommit...) But it is hard to tell unless you post the detailed data structure...

Comment: If the table `student` has a foreign key reference to `person`, then you need to insert the corresponding `personId` to the refering field in `student`.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: a look at your person + student table schema would help here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `student` table probably has a `personId` field, which references the `person` table. You must fill that, too (in your second insert).

Also, you'd better place both inserts inside a transaction, so you don't end up with inconsistent, or kinda-working, data. With a transaction, you'll either get both records or none, not one of them like you do now.

Comment: Is there a way to instead of having an extra txtbox asking for the same ID, to somehow get the code to see what the id I inserted above was and then it fills it out automatically?

Comment: yeah, my `person` table has a column called `personId`, that is the primary key of `person`. My student table has a column called `person_personId`, is there a way for this column to get filled auto?

Comment: @user2469932 - Change your insert statement for student to `"INSERT INTO student(majorField, gradePointAverage, person_personId) VALUES (@majorField, @gradePointAverage, @person_personId)"` and add the parameter with `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@person_personId", personId);`

Comment: I wish there was a different way but I guess this will do

Answer (score 0):

It appears you have a "one-one" relationship between `Person` and `Student`, and I'm guessing `Student` has a `PersonId` foreign key, so you need to add that.

```
string myInsertSQLStudent = "INSERT INTO student(personId, majorField, gradePointAverage) VALUES (@majorField, @gradePointAverage)";
            cmd.Prepare();
            cmd.CommandText = myInsertSQLStudent;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@personId", personId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@majorField", majorField);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gradePointAverage", gradePointAverage);
            prevID(conn, cmd);
```

On your first insert you should return the id of inserted record - you can call `select @@identity` as the last statement and use `var id = cmd.ExecuteScalar()` to get at it

```
  string myInsertSQL = "INSERT INTO person(personId, firstName, lastName, DOB, phoneNumber, address, postCode) VALUES (@personId, @firstName, @lastName, @DOB, @phoneNumber, @address, @postCode); 
select @@identity as id";
```